# Перенести строку в другую таблицу

Tags: php, mysql

Выводятся данные из бд.К каждой записи прикрепляется кнопка,по нажатию на которую я получаю id этой записи,это работает успешно

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['su1']))
   {

  $id=$_POST['id'];
  $sql = "DELETE from  zayavka where id=$id;";
  $query= mysql_query($sql);

  }
```

Мне необходимо эту запись перенести в другую таблицу,где такие же поля.Как это сделать зная только id записи?
Или же придется передавать все значения так же как я id передавал?

Comment: Вы sql-инъекций не боитесь?

Comment: Не очень знаком с механизмом защиты от инъекций

Comment: @zkolya, добавьте в таблицу `zayavka` поле `is_archived` и не плодите костылей.

Comment: Спасибо,так и сделал)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
insert into othertable select * from thetable where id=$id
```

Comment: чет ругается $sql="insert into archive select * from zayavka where id=$id";
$query= mysql_query(sql);

Comment: 1) как ругается? 2) можно для страховки от select и до конца в скобки взять

Comment: Use of undefined constant sql - assumed 'sql' вот содержимое sql INSERT INTO archive (select * from zayavka where id='5')

Comment: :)))) $sql - доллар добавьте. Можно по почте

Comment: $query= mysql_query(sql); - вот здесь, в скобках

Comment: да нашел,спасибо)А не затруднит ли Вас подсказать,как мне сделать так что бы в архив добавлялось без id

Comment: он в описании второй таблицы есть?

Comment: Да он есть,но таблица,в которую добавляются данные дубликат 1 таблицы,тот id записывается в этот,вот где проблема

Comment: т.е. вы хотите их сделать независимымы? не очень понятно, но ладно. а он там автоинкремент?

Comment: не,смотрите.Есть 2 таблицы архив и заявка.Задумка такая при нажатие на кнопку текущая запись из таблицы заявка попадает в архив.Сейчас она полностью туда переноситься вместе со значением id заявки,мне нужно что б у архива свой id был как бы думал может как то так $sql="INSERT INTO `archive` (select usluga,corp_name,name,mail,phone,dop_info,date from `zayavka` where id='$id')"; перечислить через запятую,но не работает

Comment: говорит, что не совпадает кол-во полей? если сделать поле id автоинкремент, как я понимаю, должно заработать.

Comment: Увидал, там синтаксис чуть другой `INSERT INTO archive (usluga,corp_name,name,mail,phone,dop_info,date) (select usluga,corp_name,name,mail,phone,dop_info,date from zayavka where id='$id')`Но про автоинкремент - это всяко правильно

Comment: Все равно ,id тот записывается

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/565d7c/1